# function overwrite sessaion details

Tags: php

weired thing -

I create session with user details (`userID`, `userName`, etc) in the LOGIN part .

```
$_SESSION['userDetails'] = array("userID" => $index['id'], "userTitle" =>  $index['title'], "userName" => $index['name'], "userIP" => getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") );
```

than I create function that pull user details from the DB and insert them in the same variable name as my session. that make my session lose it values!
how come?

```
$userDetails =  get_user_details ($_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'], "");
function get_user_details ($userID, $parameter)
{   
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (id = '$userID')");
    $index = mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if (empty($parameter))
        return ($index);
    else 
        return ($index[$parameter]);
}
```

does variable and session are the same thing/object?

I mean - does `$_SESSION['userDetails']` =  `$userDetails` ???

Thanks

Comment: where have you defined your $userdetails ?

Comment: @CodeLover - in some page I have. I define it when I call the function : $userDetails =  get_user_details (...). why?

Comment: Is the value lost on the same page or another? Be sure U add `session_start()` at the top of each page where u need session values

Comment: I think you should run a foreach after u get the data from mysql and manually set in the session

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an old version of PHP it may be the case. If register_globals (php.ini) is set to ON, this will be also the case.

Edit : Of course, setting this variable to ON is NOT recommanded. You may have security issue.

Comment: I changed "register_globals" to ON in my loal server and its works fine (the issue is only on the share sever)

Comment: Don't enable "register_globals". It may have some problem and secuity bug for you.